Fragment view is re-creating every time in BottomNavBar
In my android app I'm using bottomNavBar with 3 items,  [Home,Dashboard,Notification] those are fragments. whenever Im clicking Home or Dashboard fragment view with viewModel also is re-creating. to navigate on each fragment I'm using android navigation component (NavHost).
I tried  to load those three fragments at the same time in fragment containerView, with hide/show option , instead of using navigationComponent. but this approach is not suitable for my app.
So my question is How to maintain  those three fragment state  after first creation. using navigation component
